# How to tell if an app is using Okuma API

Tags: api, okuma, certify

I'm looking for a simple way to tell if an app is using the Okuma API. There are several applications running on a control and I don't see any indication. I've tried renaming the Okuma API dll's and I can make some of them crash by not being able to find them but that can't be the best way.

I'm writing my own app too, I want to follow the standard. Is there any built in splash screen or standard way to show an app is using the API? (Something like Intel-Inside but Okuma THINC Inside, etc) I've tried searching for the Okuma logos and I see several different versions being used but none that signify anything about API and none that really look standard for indicating API usage.

Answer (score 2):

At this time there is no official logo for the purpose your describing.

Comment: Is there any standard way to tell if an application is using the API?

Comment: You could always use depends. (the dependency walker, not the accident keeper) Get it from http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @Okuma.Tony That does not work if the application is using the API through reflection.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott ask it as a new question. I don't think there is *any* way at all to test for what is essentially a run-time import of a dll.